# Trouble Reinstalling macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, partition

My dad was running macOS & Windows on his Early 2015 MacBook Air, and both crashed. Apple’s service center said the only option was to reinstall macOS.

Using the Windows Command Prompt I backed up as much data as I could. Then I tried to reinstall Sierra, but couldn’t boot into the Recovery Partition. Internet Recovery never worked (at best it progressed to 10% then stopped).

So I deleted all my partitions and downloaded a Sierra image from someone who put it in Google Drive. I don’t know what I did wrong but it turned my hard drive into an “OS X Base System.”

[image: HDD showing as OS X Base System in Disk Utility]

I tried resetting SMC, PVRAM/NVRAM… Nothing worked.

Now when I start the Mac normally it tries to resume the macOS installation, but fails because the HDD contains an “OS Installation Media.”

Then I got my hands on a friend’s Mac that I used to [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372). I now have the USB boot drive, but I cannot boot to it (it shows the Apple logo and then “No Entry”). Trying to boot to the regular HDD also shows “No Entry.”

I would appreciate any help reinstalling my Mac cleanly.

Comment: Are you sure you are booting off the installer? While holding the Option Key did you select "Install macOS Sierra"?

Comment: The Partition Map on the [tiny] photo shows as Master Boot Record, which is incorrect; it must be GUID to be used as an OS X boot disk. Make sure the SanDisk isn't formatted the same.

Comment: @matteo yes. I am sure I'm selecting "install macOS Sierra'. It does the samething when i try with the hdd too.

Comment: @Tetsujin i agree. How do i bring back to GUID with my current situation. No recovery options work. Cant boot to usb.

Comment: @KrishnaKotharu What disk utilty is the one in the picture? Coming from the usb or the hdd?

Comment: @Matteo's point is salient - if you're booted from the SSD, you could re-format the USB from there, but then re-make the installer, bootable, in whatever you made it in the first place. Basically, you can only deal with the drive you're not currently booted from.

Comment: @matteo it is the hdd and hence it doesnt allow me to erase it.

Comment: @tetsujin doesnt seem to be an issue with usb..the only issue is i cant seem to boot to it to format the hdd..

Comment: As @Tetsujin pointed out, the partition scheme must be GUID in order for the usb to boot. Go to your friend's Mac again, format the usb and recreate the install media

Comment: The usb itself is GUID..The MBR we see in the pic is the mac hard drive.

Comment: Test the USB will boot the Mac it was made on - that would eliminate the USB itself as the issue

Comment: Good idea..can only try that tmrw...

Comment: Couldn't test the usb itself but i took my mac to apple service center again and they were unabke to boot to their usb..

Comment: The service technician called and said the ssd works fine on another mac. But others don't work on mine. He says its got to do with the motherboard which somehow seems hard to believe. Any further suggestions?? Is there a way to reset the motherboard just in case it saves any logs??

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide to get you going again.

Not sure if your question needs to be closed as too broad / too much 20 questions - technical support, but following Apple's erase and install process should fix this at the cost of any data you still have on that drive.

[Can't start Mac in recovery mode - only get folder with question mark instead](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337834/cant-start-mac-in-recovery-mode-only-get-folder-with-question-mark-instead)