# Can't start Mac in recovery mode - only get folder with question mark instead

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, restart

I can't start my MacBook Pro 2017 using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

For all combinations I only get the folder with a question mark shown.

What can it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try this Press and hold the Option key immediately after turning on or restarting your Mac.
Release the Option key when you see the Startup Manager window.

Comment: In addition to @Buscar웃 's question, do you mean the **command** key instead of the Control key you're asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy - the folder with a question mark means no bootable volume is connected to the computer despite what disk used to be the startup disk was in the past.

You'll want to connect to a WiFi or wired network and try booting to internet recovery or bring a known good bootable OS to this machine so you can boot to disk utility and see if the internal drive needs first aid or a wipe and erase.

> To manually start up from macOS Recovery over the Internet, hold down Option-Command-R or Shift-Option-Command-R at startup.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Barring that, you'll need to seek hardware service if you don't have internet boot or a way to bring a bootable OS to this Mac.

The only one thing to try is resetting the NVRAM one time. Hold Command - Option - P - R at boot and make sure you hear the startup chime twice before letting go.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

[image: Apple support image showing option + command + P + R]
All the other commands won't help get you past the folder with a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

My way out was to erase and reinstall macOS:

1. Burn a USB key with MacOS Catalina or Mojave on it (follow instructions on internet: https://support.apple.com/sl-si/HT201372)
2. Plug the USB with your future MacOS on your Mac, restart the mac and hold the `Alt` button down (if it doesn't work with the `Alt` use the `cmd`).
3. Now you will see the option to boot from that USB, choose that option, erase the HD where you want to install your MacOS and you are good to go