# need help I screwed my macbook so bad thiere is one drive and no partitions, please read below

Tags: high-sierra, partition, startup, software

So...I somehow messed up my macbook Pro model 1502 raetina 13" Late 2013, core i5, 4GB. I wanted to clean install High Sierra.  Long story short I now have a macbook with one, yes one, there is no base drive, there are no partitions at all.  I can't seem to find anywhere to download an installable version of high sierra anywhere.  Is it possible to make a boot drive from the macos that I can boot with to erase my one drive?  I'm sure there is a lot I don't know nor have thought of.  I greately appreciate any help you can offer

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of many questions where you boot to Recovery and re-partition / re-download an installer and set up a new OS.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

You can bring another bootable volume to the Mac as well or bring a bootable installer or just a drive with a local recovery partition as well. You don't have to erase anything - main thing is to get another OS running so you can decide if you need to backup or do data recovery. If you have a full backup or can walk away from all the data - just erase the volume and set up a new OS.

- [Can't start Mac in recovery mode - only get folder with question mark instead](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337834/cant-start-mac-in-recovery-mode-only-get-folder-with-question-mark-instead)